# cat and more has different output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

When I try to do the following both the outputs are different:

```
$ cat /var/log/log

BACKUP-2017_12_30_03-35-02.ta 100% 5330MB  14.2MB/s   06:16

BACKUP-2018_01_09_03-35-02.ta 100% 5342MB  14.7MB/s   06:03

BACKUP-2018_01_02_03-35-02.ta 100% 5312MB  14.6MB/s   06:03

BACKUP-2018_01_06_03-35-02.ta 100% 5328MB  14.4MB/s   06:11
```

`more /var/log/log` has the same output as above but with everything from 1% to 100%.

I have to use the output of cat in the script below, but when I do it the output will be the output same as more.

```
echo "Below are the files copied during RUN" && echo -e "\n----- Contents -----\n" && cat /var/log/log) | tr -dc '[[:print:]]' | mailx -v \
```

Comment: Give more information please. First, in Linux, `/var/log/` is directory, and you can't use `cat` on it.

Comment: sorry i have corrected it. its log inside log

Comment: I wondered about a null byte in the input, but got the opposite (in Cygwin) --- `cat` kept going after the null, but `more` stopped at the null.

Comment: try `cat -v /var/log/log` and see the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [`cat` command not reading all data in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430936/cat-command-not-reading-all-data-in-text-file)

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but some versions of more/less simply run `cat` if the output is a pipe (not a tty).  I only mention it because it matters when you're trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There are some special characters and sequences which are used on the console, these special characters are used for various purposes like for example moving the cursor position, but also producing sounds and setting various terminal options. These are called escape sequences, for example you can read about them here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code .
Doing `cat <file>` on a (normal) console terminal will/should parse most/some escape sequence. You may see the output of the command saved to a file like this command would be running on a terminal (puff, i don't know how to explain it, see my example below). `more` parses escape sequences somewhat intelligent, so the output is more user friendly.
Let's show it on an example. Imagine you are downloading a file with wget:

```
$ wget http://www.ac6-tools.com/downloads/SW4STM32/install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run
--2018-01-12 14:10:37--  http://www.ac6-tools.com/downloads/SW4STM32/install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run
Resolving www.ac6-tools.com... 37.59.46.135
Connecting to www.ac6-tools.com|37.59.46.135|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 433081872 (413M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run.5’

        install_sw4stm32_linux_   0%[                                                      ]   2.91M  1.42MB/s
```

The last line 'changes/refreshes itself', i mean, wget produces escape sequences to move the cursor position to the beginning of the line (probably '\r') and prints the line again, thus refreshing it. Now we will trick wget to think it's output is console and save it's stderr and stdout output to a file /tmp/1.

```
 unbuffer wget http://www.ac6-tools.com/downloads/SW4STM32/install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run >&/tmp/1
```

Now lets:

```
$ cat /tmp/1
--2018-01-12 14:10:27--  http://www.ac6-tools.com/downloads/SW4STM32/install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run
Resolving www.ac6-tools.com... 37.59.46.135
Connecting to www.ac6-tools.com|37.59.46.135|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 433081872 (413M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run.4’

     install_sw4stm32_linux_64b   1%[                                                      ]   5.87M  2.63MB/s
```

However this is not exactly the contents of the file. For example in vim you may see:

```
$ vim /tmp/1
--2018-01-12 14:10:27--  http://www.ac6-tools.com/downloads/SW4STM32/install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run
Resolving www.ac6-tools.com... 37.59.46.135
Connecting to www.ac6-tools.com|37.59.46.135|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 433081872 (413M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run.4’

^M                install_sw4stm3   0%[                                                      ]       0  --.-KB/s               ^M               install_sw4stm32   0%[                                                      ] 596.40K  2.91MB/s               ^M              install_sw4stm32_   0%[                                                      ]   1.66M  4.14MB/s               ^M             install_sw4stm32_l   0%[                                                      ]   2.41M  4.01MB/s               ^M            install_sw4stm32_li   0%[                                                      ]   3.11M  3.87MB/s               ^M           install_sw4stm32_lin   0%[                                                      ]   3.60M  3.57MB/s               ^M          install_sw4stm32_linu   0%[                                                      ]   3.94M  3.23MB/s               ^M         install_sw4stm32_linux   1%[                                                      ]   4.30M  3.02MB/s               ^M        install_sw4stm32_linux_   1%[                                                      ]   4.69M  2.88MB/s               ^M       install_sw4stm32_linux_6   1%[                                                      ]   5.08M  2.78MB/s               ^M      install_sw4stm32_linux_64   1%[                                                      ]   5.48M  2.70MB/s               ^M     install_sw4stm32_linux_64b   1%[                                                      ]   5.87M  2.63MB/s
```

Those `^M` signs in the output it's the way vim is telling you, there is a special character there (not characters `^` and `M`, but a special escape sequence/character). In this case it is the escape sequence used for moving cursor to the beginning of the file. 
more is somewhat intelligent in parsing escape sequences:

```
$ more /tmp/1
--2018-01-12 14:10:27--  http://www.ac6-tools.com/downloads/SW4STM32/install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run
Resolving www.ac6-tools.com... 37.59.46.135
Connecting to www.ac6-tools.com|37.59.46.135|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 433081872 (413M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits-v2.3.run.4’

             install_sw4stm32_l   0%[                                                      ]   2.41M  4.01MB/s               
         install_sw4stm32_linux   1%[                                                      ]   4.30M  3.02MB/s               
     install_sw4stm32_linux_64b   1%[                                                      ]   5.87M  2.63MB/s
```

Hope that will clarify your inconsistency with cat and more output.